# Why are lambic and other sours/wilds bottled in green bottles?

Tags: bottling, sour, lambics

I'm familiar with the science behind light contamination, skunking, and why most beers are bottled in brown bottles.

What I'm curious is why some breweries are choosing to bottle their sours in green bottles. I've seen this for 250mL up to 750mL bottles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very little hops in a lambic so it's much less susceptible to being light struck.

They also tend to use aged hops and full duration additions.

Basically there is very little alpha-acid if any that are not isomoerized.  So there is much less of the precursors to 3-MBT (compound responsible for skunky aroma)

While they can still skunk from being light struck the brewers must feel green bottles suffice when handled correctly.